# How do I configure a Cisco 3600 Router as a second router, being SURE to not interfere with the existing production network?

Tags: router

Basically, I would like to set up a little lab here at work.  We have a spare 3600 router sitting around, as well as some new-in-box RV042s that will be in production soon.  I'd like to set up and test the tunnels before sending them out to the remote locations.

Specifically, I'd like to hook the 3600 WAN up to the network here in the office.  I'll hook an RV0 to the LAN.

I realize this is not technically difficult, I just CANNOT forget something or other, and have this 3600 start handing out IPs, or advertising routes, etc...

Generalities are fine (though specifics are welcome), but what are the pitfalls I should be wary of?  This router has an existing config on it.  Are there any lines that I should be on the lookout for?

In the end, I just want a nice little walled off corner of the network that I can play around in, and still hit the internet.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Instead simulate your own WAN within your lab, all you need is a Cisco switch you can (L3 would be preferable, as you can add routing complexity later) you can spare. This will cause no security issues until your confident with your tunnels, however unless the device is a production unit I would recommend against connecting any lab or test equipment to your WAN directly without properly security scrutiny.

Comment: The 3600 has been designated a spare/backup production unit, though it has never been set up as such.  You're right, of course, I don't actually need to have internet access from within the lab.  I just thought I'd complicate it on purpose to force... something, I don't know what :)  I think in the end, That's what I'll do though.  I also have a couple more RV0s to add to the mix.  I think I'll make the 3600 the "cloud" and set the tunnels up across it.

Comment: Should also update what type of tunnels you are using IPsec or GRE, etc?

Comment: Using IPsec gateway to gateway tunnels, hub and spoke, to connect remote locations.  Different subnets with static routes set up at the hub.